# File still open after File.AppendAllText

Tags: c#, .net, ioexception, w3wp

I have a part of my code that writes to a text file. This is the only process active that is supposed to write to the file, and here is how it's done:

```
try
{
    File.AppendAllText(path, '\n' + tmp);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    lblError.Text = "Unable to save file";
}
```

This works fine like half of the time. But sometimes it throws an exception saying that the file is being used by another process. I looked up what process uses the file, and its `w3wp.exe`.  I've read that `File.AppendAllText` closes the file once it's done with it, so it should be fine like I've done it. Right?

**EDIT:**

Description of purpose was requested, so here goes. This part of the code is supposed to append a line to a config textfile that another process will use. I am 100% certain that that process isn't currently running.

I might also add that this is an asp.net application (from code behind). So a user can write to config.txt from an asp-page.

I've tried this:

```
static readonly object saveLock = new object();
/*
 *  stuff
 */
protected void saveToConfig(string input)
{
    lock(saveLock)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(path, '\n' + input);
    }
}
```

But I still get the IOException-error saying that multiple processes are trying to access the file.

Comment: As you have `w3wp.exe` I guess you are in a multi-threaded environment (multiple requests to IIS) => two threads are accessing the file in paralell?

Comment: That seems to be the case, yes. I'm actually not sure since the majority of the code isn't my work ^^. If that is the case, I guess a simple lock would suffice?

Comment: Yes, a lock should help, BUT I think a basic design flaw is present...

Comment: ok.. care to elaborate? =)

Comment: May give me a short description, what dis part should do? Write a log?

Comment: @ChrFin I added some further explaining in the question. Please have a look at my edit =)

Comment: Is this other process executed after every "append" or on a sheduled basis? Is there no other way to supply this configuration?

Comment: @ChrFin I think this other process is supposed to be running in the background and look for new config on a set time interval or something. Not sure though. And no, I've recieved orders that this is how we want it done.

Comment: That sounds like a job for a database or something similar. A "common text-file" will definitely cause problems sooner or later in the scenario as you described it so far...

Comment: @ChrFin well, this is what I have to work with regardless of how much I like it.

Comment: ...then you need to work with such cases, as you can not avoid them -> e.g. make some logic which repeates the append if it fails...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Palmer](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Palmer/) to create some logic, which repeats the write if it fails:

```
Retry.On<IoException>().For(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)).With(context =>
    {
        File.AppendAllText(path, '\n' + tmp);
    });
```